# Can WPF Controls be re-used?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

For example, I have created a button with a check mark drawn on it.  I need to use it in a couple places in my window.

```
<Button Width="25">
    <!-- Draw a Green checkmark -->
    <Polyline Points="2,5,6,10,13,1" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" />
</Button>
```

Since I only want to change the content, I'm not sure if Styles or Templates apply.  Do I need to create a UserControl?

**Edit:** This can be accomplished with a style.  But, I only want to change the content and I don't want to override the current style.

Comment: You better can use a style here so that you need not go and change all your Buttons when there is a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is crying out for a style.  Add the following Style to your Window.Resources:

```
<style TargetType="Button" x:Key="tick">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Polyline Points="2,5,6,10,13,1" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and you can then define your button as:

```
<Button Width="25" Style="{StaticResource tick}" />
```

Comment: This particular style meets the requirement, but it discards any Content supplied for the Button using the Style.  It's a good solution, however as you can always modify the template to include a ContentPresenter later.  For instance, you could create a horizontal StackPanel with the Polyline followed by the ContentPresenter and now you could optionally append text (or any other content for that matter) to any 'tick' style button.

Comment: That is a very good point - I did work to rule on it.  Adding a content presenter would be a nice feature.

Comment: Thanks.  But my whole application already has styles applied to it. When I apply this style I loose all that.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: @TheSean, You can use the BasedOn property of the Style to use another style as the base.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx

Comment: I don't know the theme at design time, so it would need to be dynamic.  From what I've read, that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @TheSean, check out the style based on the default style for the control type.  i.e. `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"`

Comment: I think you actually need to use BasedOn="{DynamicResource {x:Type Button}}" if the style can change at run time as he was saying.  I think that will work.

Comment: @Craig: Thanks, but this doesn't fly.

A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'BasedOn' property of type 'Style'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: @TheSean It would appear the only recourse would be to make a user control containing the button with the check content.  That's not a great solution but I can't think of any other way to get around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a UserControl with the contents of the button you created if you want to have some sort of dynamic capability to it i.e. add new properties.  If you just have a button that just has the visual appearance to have a check then I'd use a style.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UserControl with the contents of the button you created. The easiest option to create the user control is to use Expression Blend. Select all of our controls to whom u want to make UserControl. Right Click and Select "make into Usercontrol". Thats it. U can use this control anywhere in your project just by drag and drop.

Hope it will help u,

Saghar Ayyaz